# How can I edit the original array throughout all of my functions C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a sodoku program and I need to find a way to edit the same array in all of my functions. I have read that pointers can be used for this but I do not really know how to use pointers very well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char upperCase(char letter)
{
   int decVal = (int) letter;
   if (decVal >= 97 && decVal <= 122)
      decVal -= 32;
   letter = (char) decVal;
   return letter;
}

void readFile(int board[9][9])
{
   char fileName[256];
   int row = 0;
   int col = 0;
   cout << "Where is your board located? ";
   cin >> fileName;
   ifstream fin(fileName);
   while (fin >> board[row][col])
   {
      col++;
      if (col == 9)
      {
         row++;
         col = 0;
      }
   }

}

void displayOptions()
{
   cout << "Options:" << endl;
   cout << "   ?  Show these instructions" << endl;
   cout << "   D  Display the board" << endl;
   cout << "   E  Edit one square" << endl;
   cout << "   S  Show the possible values for a square" << endl;
   cout << "   Q  Save and quit" << endl;
   cout << endl;
}

void displayBoard(int board[9][9])
{
   int row = 0;
   int col = 0;
   int rowNum = 1;
   bool onSide = true;
   cout << "   A B C D E F G H I" << endl;
   while (row <= 8)
   {
      if ((row == 3 || row == 6) && col == 0)
         cout << "   -----+-----+-----" << endl;

      if (onSide)
      {
         cout << rowNum << " ";
         onSide = false;
      }

      if (col == 3 || col == 6)
         cout << "|";
      else
         cout << " ";

      if (board[row][col] == 0)
         cout << " ";
      else
         cout << board[row][col];
      col++;

      if (col == 9)
      {
         row++;
         col = 0;
         rowNum++;
         onSide = true;
         cout << endl;
      }
   }
}

void editSquare(int board[9][9])
{
   char cord[2];
   int row;
   int col;
   bool run = true;
   bool fail = false;
   while (run)
   {
      run = false;
      fail = false;
      cout << "What are the coordinates of the square: ";
      cin >> cord;

      if (cord[0] == 'A' || cord[0] == 'a')
         row = 0;
      else if (cord[0] == 'B' || cord[0] == 'b')
         row = 1;
      else if (cord[0] == 'C' || cord[0] == 'c')
         row = 2;
      else if (cord[0] == 'D' || cord[0] == 'd')
         row = 3;
      else if (cord[0] == 'E' || cord[0] == 'e')
         row = 4;
      else if (cord[0] == 'F' || cord[0] == 'f')
         row = 5;
      else if (cord[0] == 'G' || cord[0] == 'g')
         row = 6;
      else if (cord[0] == 'H' || cord[0] == 'h')
         row = 7;
      else if (cord[0] == 'I' || cord[0] == 'i')
         row = 8;
      else
      {
         cout << "ERROR: Square '";
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            cout << cord[i];
         cout << "' is invalid" << endl;
         run = true;
         fail = true;
      }

      if (!fail)
      {
         if (cord[1] == '1')
            col = 0;
         else if (cord[1] == '2')
            col = 1;
         else if (cord[1] == '3')
            col = 2;
         else if (cord[1] == '4')
            col = 3;
         else if (cord[1] == '5')
            col = 4;
         else if (cord[1] == '6')
            col = 5;
         else if (cord[1] == '7')
            col = 6;
         else if (cord[1] == '8')
            col = 7;
         else if (cord[1] == '9')
            col = 8;
         else
         {
            cout << "ERROR: Square '";
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
               cout << cord[i];
            cout << "' is invalid" << endl;
            run = true;
         }
      }
   }

   cord[0] = upperCase(cord[0]);

   if (board[row][col] == 0)
   {
      int number;
      cout << "What is the value at '";
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         cout << cord[i];
      cout << "': ";
      cin >> number;
      if (number >= 0 && number <= 9)
         board[row][col] = number;
      else
      {
         cout << "ERROR: Value '" << number << "' in square '";
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            cout << cord[i];
         cout << "' is invalid" << endl;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "ERROR: Square '";
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         cout << cord[i];
      cout << "' is filled" << endl;
   }
}

bool writeFile(int board[9][9])
{
   int row = 0;
   int col = 0;
   char fileName[256];
   cout << "What file would you like to write your board to: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   ofstream fout(fileName);
   while (row <= 8)
   {
      fout << board[row][col] << " ";
      col++;
      if (col == 9)
      {
         row++;
         col = 0;
         fout << endl;
      }
   }
   cout << "Board written successfully" << endl;
   return false;
}

bool getCommand(int board[9][9])
{
   bool run = true;
   char input;
   cout << endl << "> ";
   cin >> input;

   input = upperCase(input);

   if (input == '?')
      displayOptions();
   else if (input == 'D')
      displayBoard(board);
   else if (input == 'E')
      editSquare(board);
   else if (input == 'S');
   else if (input == 'Q')
   {
      run = writeFile(board);
   }
   else
      cout << "ERROR: Invalid command" << endl;

   return run;
}

int main()
{
   bool run = true;
   int board[9][9];
   readFile(board);
   displayOptions();
   displayBoard(board);
   while (run)
      run = getCommand(board);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code already has all of the functions operating on the same board. Please clarify what you are asking about.  If your code does not behave as you expected, then post what you expected and explain how this differs from what you observed.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't  pass uniform-dimension arrays in this fashion:

```
bool writeFile(int board[9][9]);
```

you initialize your array ONCE:

```
int board[9][9];
```

Then, you pass it to a method,specifying how long each row is, aka the column count ONLY, in the case of a 2D construct. Such a method signature would look like this:

```
bool writeFile(int board[][9]);
```

Within writeFile, board IS the same array you passed in, NOT a copy by value to which you may be accustomed.
If you use c style arrays, you're using pointers whether you like it or not, because all an array variable in fact is IS a pointer to the first array element. For example:

```
//given
int array[9];
//array can be passed into a method signed "void DoSomethingWithArray(int* array);
//or a method signed "void DoSomethingWithArray(int array[]);
```

and all changes made in such a method affect array, the original declaration variable.

In the case of passing a 2D array, "board" in your case, the parameter board decays into(is programtically) a pointer to an int array, aka a pointer to the first row of your construct, which in turn is a pointer to the first element(int) of your construct. This fact shouldn't overtly matter, because you can double subscript it to access any elements in the familiar way. Knowing this is important though, as you wouldn't wonder how to manipulate the same array in various functions once you know that the way they get there is by address, not by value.

One additional note that may shed light on some of these points:

```
array[1]; 
//is the same as
*(array + 1);
//take the address of the first array element, move index*sizeof(elementT) addresses forward,
 //and then dereference. [] is just a syntactical abstraction of this behavior.
```

Comment: Actually I just applied your suggestion and it seemed to fix my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's likely that your problem lies in where you perceive you're changing the value. I would declare a sample board in main, edit some values manually, and pass it to your write function. If it prints the modified values, you know your problem occurs where you're editing the array, not in getting it to your writing function.

Comment: @DanielCollins No problem!

Comment: Yeah that was the issue I had the rows and columns switched. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It's completely correct to write `bool writeFile(int board[9][9]);` , and also good self-documentation if it should only ever be called with an array of 9 rows. Also "an array variable in fact is a pointer" is false. Arrays and pointers are different.  A pointer may point to an array element but that does not make the two identical.

Comment: @M.M Yes, an array identifier only _decays_ into a pointer implicitly, but you'd be hard pressed to find a circumstance where regarding one parametrically as a const pointer would ever lead to semantic failure/ambiguity, 
And yes, row count omission is optional, but the omission can help elucidate the array-of-arrays underlay of a 2D c-style array, at the expense of enforcing that a uniform array is expected.

Comment: @M.M Further enforcing the array-pointer association is the fact that any pointer can be sub-scripted with [0] to dereference it, as if it were a single element array.
int* i = new int;
i[0] = 69;
I'm not advising this be done, but it is valid C++ nevertheless.

Comment: `&arr` is a simple example of where regarding an array as a pointer leads to confusion. As is `sizeof arr`. The behaviour of the `[]` operator doesn't change the definition of an array or a pointer.

Comment: @M.M I guess you weren't as hard-pressed as I anticipated.